# Pairing People in R with Loop

Tags: r, loops, sorting

I am trying to create pen-pal pairs in R. The problem is that I can't figure out how to loop it so that once I pair one person that person and their pair are eliminated from the pool and the loop continues until everyone has a pair.

I have already rated the criteria to pair them and found a score for every person for how well they would pair for the other person. I think added every pair score together to get a sense of how good the pair is overall (not perfect, but good enough for these purposes). I have found each person's ideal match then and ordered these matches by most picky person to least picky person (basically person with the lowest best-paired score to highest best-paired score). I also found their 2nd-8th best match (there will probably be about 300 people in the data).

A test of the best-matches is below:

```
   indexed_fake apply.fin_fake..1..max. X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
14           14                     151  3  9  8  4 10 12  2  6
4             4                     177  9  5  8  7 11  3 10 12
9             9                     177  4 11  3  6 10  7 12  5
5             5                     179  7  4 11  3 12 10  8  5
10           10                     179 12 10  2  9  3  5  6  4
13           13                     182  8  1 12 11 10  5  3  2
1             1                     185  7  1  3  8  6 13  2 11
7             7                     185  1 12  5  7  4  6  9 11
3             3                     187 12  3  8  5  9  1  2 10
8             8                     190  8 12 13  3  4 11  1  6
2             2                     191  6 12 11 10  3  4  5  1
6             6                     191  2 11  7  1  6  9 10  8
11           11                     193 12  6  9  5  2  8 11  4
12           12                     193 11  3  8  7 12 10  2  5
```

Columns X1-X8 are the 8 best pairs for the people listed in the first columns. With this example every person would ideally get paired with someone in their top 8, ideally maximizing the pair compatibility as another user mentioned. Every person would get one pair.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is no code showing with this question.  When requesting assistance, it is necessary to show the code and data sources.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a specific answer.  But it's easier to write in this space.  You have a classic assignment optimization problem.  These problems can be solved using packages in R.  You have to assign preference weights to your feasible pairings.  So for example 14-3 could be assigned 8 points, 14-9; 7 points, 14-8; 6 points...14-6; 1 point.  Note that 3-14 would be assigned no points because while 14 likes 3, 3 does not like 14.  The preference score for any x-y, y-x pairing could be the weight for the x-y preference plus the weight of the y-x preference.

The optimization model would choose the weighted pairs to maximize the total satisfaction among all of the the pairings.

If you have 300 people I can't think of an alternative algorithm that could be simply implemented.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any particular package you feel would be useful for this?

Comment: There are 2 packages, ROI and ompr.  ROI contains access to various solvers.  ompr is a platform for formulating your model.  It mashes up to ROI.  Info for ompr can be found here: https://dirkschumacher.github.io/ompr/  Optimization modeling is not hard, but takes some work to figure it out.  I could follow you if you try it.  Note that an input data set would be an array of the preference weights of the feasible pairs.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do it with the lpSolve package and lp.assign with each of the scores in a matrix.